# Dictionary and list with tuples manipulation python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have one list with some data in tuples:
`[('a',12), ('b',6), ('c',9), ('d',15), ('e',4)]`

After some manipulation with data a dictionary 
`{1: ['b','d'], 2: ['a','c','e']}` is created.
How could I manipulate this dictionary and initial list to retrieve a list with integers of those letters?
Like    `[[6,15],[12,9,4]]`  .

```
items = [('a',12), ('b',6), ('c',9), ('d',15), ('e',4)]
bins = {1: ['b','d'], 2: ['a','c','e']}
tempList = []
tList = []
for b in bins.keys():
    for i in range(len(bins[b])):
        if bins[b][i] == items[i][0]:
            tList.append(items[i][1])
    tempList.append(tList)
```

The output is:

```
[[12],[12]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `test_dict = dict([('a',12), ('b',6), ('c',9), ('d',15), ('e',4)])`;


`{key: [test_dict[x] for x in lst] for key, lst in {1: ['b','d'], 2: ['a','c','e']}.items()}`

Comment: @BrianJoseph your answer is good, but my goal is to output this result: [[6,15],[12,9,4]]  and yours is  {1: [6, 15], 2: [12, 9, 4]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `dict` out of the `list` of `tuples` and do something like,

```
>>> a = [('a',12), ('b',6), ('c',9), ('d',15), ('e',4)]
>>> b = {1: ['b','d'], 2: ['a','c','e']}
>>> d = {k:v for k,v in a}
>>> [[d.get(y) for y in x] for x in b.values()]
[[6, 15], [12, 9, 4]]
```

For better understanding:

```
>>> d = {k:v for k,v in a} # create a dictionary with `char: value` from list of tuples for convenience :)
>>> l = [] # create a main list
>>> for values in b.values(): # we only need the values
...   il = [] # a temporary inner list to keep values
...   for value in values:
...     val = d[value] # get the corresponding value of the character we kept in the dictionary
...     il.append(val) # append the value to the inner list
...   l.append(il) # append the inner list to main list
... 
>>> l
[[6, 15], [12, 9, 4]]
```

Comment: This is good! But I can't understand how is it working in this way for 100%?

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked like a charm. And of course thanks a lot for explanation!

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help